# MySQL 5.6 Grant tables empty

Tags: linux, security, permissions, mysql

Running MySQL 5.6 on GNU/Linux. It appears that during a physical-to-virtual moved, the Db was not properly shutdown.  This resulted in the grant tables being empty:

```
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Trying to work with any user results in a message like: `Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost'`.
How do I recover from this?  I've heard of using the `skip_grant` statement in the my.ini file but how would that allow me to write to the grant tables?
Has anyone seen this before or have suggestions?

Sorry if I did not make myself clear before.

Comment: Please edit sentence "I'm not use the skip_grant method would allow me to write to the grant tables.". Thank you.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the top answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges should be useful.